# Is debugging, programming, etc. [assembly]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, specific-question

[Is "scroll tearing" a symptom of scanline interrupts taking too long?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/22353/278) was tagged [assembly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly), [graphics](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics), [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) and [game-boy](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-boy). I took [8080](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8080) off, because the Game Boy doesn't have an 8080 in it, and I took [assembly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) off because the question isn't about assembly.

But now I'm not sure. The tag usage for [assembly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) says:

> > Assembly languages in general, of any architecture. Use with the particular processor’s tag as appropriate.
>
> For questions about the assembly language of a microprocessor or CPU.
>
> If specific to a particular processor, please also use the appropriate processor tag.

This question isn't *about* the assembly language, but it's about interrupts and cycle counting, something that you only really do *in* assembly. So did I make the right call?

Answer (score 4):

The Question seems to be more about I/O usage and timing - something that can happen with any language. It seems not to hold anything Assembly specific. So it does not contain or generate any knowledge about or related to Assembly - which is what someone looking for that tag would look for.

Just because Assembly is used to generate the example does not make it a topic.

Answer (score 2):

If the question were a generic "I see this problem in *someone else's* code and am wondering why it is happening" then I think [assembly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assembly) would *not* belong.

However, this question actually includes assembly language code, so the tag belongs here.

Comment: That a question *contains* assembly code does not make it a question *about* assembly code.  So, I'm not persuaded by the argument.